# .NET Standard reference

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I have two computers.

I was working with computer one to make a prototype of a project. I have created a .NET Standard 2.0 class library and added a .NET Framework 4.6.1 class library. I have referenced .NET Standard to .NET Framework and everything was working.

Now I've switched to computer two and done the same. There was no problem with referencing but I cannot use classes from .NET Standard project. The code is red and Resharper keep telling me

> "Reference XX ( .NET Standard ) and use XX "

This gives me no result and, when I add 'using' statement with the .NET Standard namespace the code is still red.

Do I need to download something?

Comment: I added white-space, punctuation and  fixed some spelling and grammar in your question. If you make your questions easier to read, they are more likely to get answers.

Comment: Does the solution compile properly? This might be just ReSharper acting up. It does that sometimes. Usually solved by clearing it's cache.